# How to enable Turbo Boost for a t2.micro instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

From this page I see that t2 CPU can turbo boost up to 3.3Ghz: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/. 
[image]

And this AWS official video said t2 CPU could be 60% faster than m4:https://youtu.be/FkMslBsVYFU?t=447
[image]

Then I made a testing:
Launched a t2.micro instances(ubuntu 16.04), use *sysbench* to make the CPU keep running at 100%. In the meantime I opened another terminal tab and repeated command `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`, but the result was always 2.4 (I expected 3.3). I also made the same CPU benchmark on a m4 instance and the running time was same with t2.

So, how to I make t2 CPU run 60% faster than m4 CPU?

Comment: I don't know if it can be used on a t2, but you might try `turbostat`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/processor_state_control.html

Answer (score -1):

First, you will NEVER see real MHz on cloud/virtual servers due to host OS which is designed to *emulate* real hardware instead of *be* the hardware.

Second, the charts you posted metered in ECU, not MHz.

I've made additional research, the results are below.
As you probably know, t2 instances have burst capability and during those bursts they run at more than 100% of CPU, however it can be measured in real tasks, not in MHz.

I run two instances: t2.medium and c4.large, as on the first screenshot of your video. All instances were created using the same Amazon Linux 2 LTS Candidate AMI 2017.12.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-db1688a2

To create load I used https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite/ :

```
yum install -y php php-cli php-common php-gd php-pdo php-process php-xml
mkdir tmp; cd tmp
wget http://phoronix-test-suite.com/releases/phoronix-test-suite-7.6.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf phoronix-test-suite-7.6.0.tar.gz
cd phoronix-test-suite
./phoronix-test-suite install pts/build-apache
./phoronix-test-suite batch-setup # (answers are no and no)
```

then run each of those tests three times

```
./phoronix-test-suite batch-run pts/build-apache
```

and recorded average value for each test, like here:

[image]

The results are in the chart, data are seconds, less means better:

[image]

The gain is ~20% which is les than on your screenshot but we don't know what tests were used by AWS (I asked but they didn't answer) nevertheless as you can see t2.medium was faster than c4.large.

p.s. I also run bz2 decompress test: t2.medium was slower there perhaps due to more intensive disk usage (I used the cheapest disk option).

Comment: "Inter Turbo" is listed in the table. The "server burst" should be the "burst above t2 baseline(5%,10%,etc..)" that spend CPU credit, that's not what I was talking about. I have updated my question please take a look.

Comment: @StanHou updated.

Comment: ,you said "measure performance in ECUs". Did you mean that ECU is not a measure of CPU speed?

Comment: @StanHou Imagine you are riding a bike inside flying plane. Speedometer of the bike will not show you your speed in relation to ground. The example is not strictly correct but you have the idea. 

According to the screenshot, ECU measures performance, but "Effective ECU" != MHz and speed != performance.

Comment: So in your thought, what is exactly "Effective ECU", and why you think the benchmark can not measure Effective ECU?

Comment: My thought: ECU (not 'effective') is amount of certain work that can be done during certain period of time. Certain work is very specific to test here: e.g. number of i++ loops, or i = sqrt(y) etc. This value you select when create an instance. Here are more details: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/ Effective ECU is what you have according to this performance meter in reality. 
To measure it you have to use the same testing method. Or you can use your own method however  the results should be compared not with what you see on doc but with your tests on another instances with same method.

Comment: In the question details I said that I have made a testing using `sysbench` to compare t2 CPU and m4 CPU, and the results were same. I also tested a c4 instance, which is even faster than t2. My question is how to enable Turbo Boost and how to make t2 CPU run faster than m4 in anyway.

Comment: You did not provide any details regarding test parameters. More important, you don't know what test AWS used to build those charts.

Comment: `sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 run`. Again, my original question is "how to make t2 CPU run 60% faster than m4", that already means I don't know how. No need to point out that I don't know. If you know, answer it.

Comment: Or can you imagine an example that "an amount of certain work that can be done" on a t2.large 60% faster than on a m4.large and explain why?

Comment: @StanHou Updated. Not 60% but anyway. And yes, I measured seconds, not ECUs because I don't know how to measure them.